# 2002 Camry SE - HELP - Nonworking Dashboard Gauges (speedometer, gasoline, odometer, RPM, etc) after the engine is started

Tags: camry

I have seen several comments online here about the same issue that I am having. Headlights, turn signals, brake lights, etc all work, but the dashboard does not function, I cannot see gauges for fuel, water, RPM, etc.  I was informed by a local Toyota dealership that the issue is I need a combo meter (whatever that is) installed and the cost will be around $800 installed and a day to do it. While I am not mechanic, I purchased a fuse meter to check the fuses located under the dashboard. They were are good. I realize there are "fuses" under the hood, but again I am not a mechanic and decided that was above my knowledge. I would appreciate any comments with no dashboard lights and if the fix price is reasonable. THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you saying they don't function, or just the lights are out?  Anyway all i can suggest with lmited knowledge is to check the ground on the dash.

Comment: The lights are out; any info would be great.

Comment: How could I check the ground?